# How can I get the last item from a row in an array?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
5/15/1987   18.58

6/15/1987   18.86

7/15/1987   19.86

8/15/1987   18.98

9/15/1987   18.31

10/15/1987  18.76

11/15/1987  17.78

12/15/1987  17.05

1/15/1988   16.75

...
```

I am using this code to read and parse the file:

```
import textract
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import csv

oil_value = []

with open(r"C:\Users\derek\Downloads\brent-monthly.csv", "r") as file:
    oil = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

    for lines in oil:
        
        oil_value.append(lines)

print(oil_value[1][0])

second_value = []
for item in oil_value:
    s = (oil_value[item].split())[-1] # It contains the thing that you need
    second_value.append(s)
print(second_value)
sns.distplot(second_value)
plt.show()
```

How can I get just the xx.xx number at the end of every row?

Comment: is that just plain text data? or is it all in a csv file? what's the separator then and if it's not csv, why is csv tagged? what array are you talking about?

Comment: The file is all just CSV. I got the above from the excel format.

Comment: could you copy what you have in your csv file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "the last item (an integer) from every row" So... the last column of the data? "the last item (an integer)... The array looks like this... is there a way to just get the xx.xx number at the end of every row?" I can't understand. If there are decimal points, they are **not integers**. Also: please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Please carefully note the [edit]s I made to the post to [remove noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721).

Comment: `oil_value` is a list of tuples that you get from the `csv.reader`. So why not do `second_value = [item[-1] for item in oil_value]`?

Answer (score 0):

It might solve your problem:

```
for item in arr:
    s = (arr[item].split())[-1] # It contains the thing that you need
    print(s)
# Output: 18.58
#         18.86
#         ...
```

If you need to convert it into the float, then you do like this:

```
print(float(s))
```

Comment: use `for item in iterable` instead of `for index in range(len(iterable))`

Comment: it should be now `s = item.split()[-1]`

Comment: returns this error:          s = (oil_value[item].split())[-1] # It contains the thing that you need
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: @JoeMusashi then let me please more details about what your array consists of: type of variable, form of the array and etc

Comment: @rockzxm It has a string as the first value followed by an integer. I am using a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @JoeMusashi then could you edit your question with code where you have read the elements of your csv file please?